# Repeat Tshark command when first done

Tags: debian, wireshark, tshark

I have this command that i need to repeat for ever till i stop it.
I have to send a capture to my supplier for VOIP support for a intermitent trouble.

But 10mb is taking like five minutes to complete... But its the format they asking me -_-

So do you have an idea to make this to repeat?

Thanks

Running on debian 9.8

TShark (Wireshark) 2.6.7

`` tshark -i any -b filesize:10240 -w /mnt/dav/`date '+%d%m%Y%H'`.pcap ``

Answer (score 0):

You can run the command in a `while` loop and `ctrl+c` when you want to stop it.

`while true; do tshark -i any -b filesize:10240 -w /mnt/dav/date '+%d%m%Y%H'.pcap; done`